# EL Brace notation for tags

Tags: jsf, el

Some days ago I came across the [EL Tag Wiki (Brace notation section)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) and I was wondering if the following examples would render:

```
#{[somedynamicBean]name}
#{[somedynamicBean][dynamicName]}
#{someBean[dynamicName1[dynamicName2]]}
```

Especially the first example would be greatly appreciated if it would work, because I would like to have a tag with a dynamic bean definition and a fixed getter `name`. Is there another notation for tags to achieve my requirements as described in the previous sentence?

Comment: 3 would work 1 and two no idea. Did you try?  And for 1, Where would you get the name from, and what would this solve?  can't you use a producer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two won't work. If you want to use different beans that happen to have the same method:

```java
public String getName()
```

consider:

```xml
<c:set var="bean" value="#{yourBean}" />
<c:set var="bean" value="#{yourOtherBean}" />
```

Then you can do `#{bean.name}` and it will reference whichever bean you assigned.

Comment: This is a good call, thanks. Tested it and works great. You can use `<c:set ... />` inside a custom tag and pass values dynamically.